# Select Sometimes Very Slow When Wrapper Function in Where Condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a select from a view. We limited by date range in the where condition. We have a wrapper function to translate the date from string to date.  Using the wrapper function sometimes has little to no impact but sometimes has a very large impact.

For example, the select:

```sql
select *
from my_view
where regdate >= dates.date_from_iso_local_datetime_string('2023-12-01T00:00:00')
  and regdate < dates.date_from_iso_local_datetime_string('2024-01-01T00:00:00')
order by id;
```

is functionally identical to:

```sql
select *
from my_view
where regdate >= to_date('2023-12-01T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
  and regdate < to_date('2024-01-01T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
order by id;
```

In one environment they run at the same performance.  In another, the `to_date` version takes around 0.8 seconds and the `dates` version around seven seconds.  In another, the `to_date` version takes around one second and the `dates` version over seven *minutes*!  In that last environment, it seems to depend on the user - if you run as schema owner it's quicker, if you run as another user it's very slow.

In the actual example the view is quite complex, it's actually three selects union:ed together but all have the same base table which is where the `regdate` column is.

The function in the `dates` package is

```sql
gcIso8601DateTimeFormat constant varchar2(23) := 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS';

function date_from_iso_local_datetime_string( pDateTimeString in varchar2 ) return date is
begin
   if trim(pDateTimeString) is null then
      return null;
   else
      return to_date(pDateTimeString, gcIso8601DateTimeFormat);
   end if;
end;
```

In the environment that was really slow, the whole view is around 4 million records but the select in question only returns one.

As near as we can tell, it must be re-evaluating the `dates` function for each row (although it seemed to be sorting at the same time - I thought it applied the conditions before sorting the result set it ends up with?)

I've searched but the examples where people have issues with functions in the `where`  clause usually seem to involve putting fields from the table through the functions.  In that case I understand that it needs to run for each row, but I would have thought it was smart enough to realise the inputs here are fixed (only constants/bound variables as input to the function) and evaluate the function once then apply to the `where` clause.

I tried re-writing as

```sql
with foo as (
   select dates.date_from_iso_local_datetime_string('2023-12-01T00:00:00') fromdate
          dates.date_from_iso_local_datetime_string('2024-01-01T00:00:00') todate
   from dual ) 
select *
from myview,
     foo
where regdate >= foo.fromdate
  and regdate < foo.todate
order by id;
```

to make it realise it could evaluate the function once but it did not help.

The actual use case is a Java API making the call.  I ran it manually to troubleshoot.  The idea of the function was just to standardise the calls from the API.  Thought using a constant for the format would help rather than hurt performance but doesn't seem to.

**Questions**

1. Main question is how to solve this?  E.g. is there some annotation I can put on the function so that the optimiser realizes it can run it once and doesn't need to keep revaluating for each row? [1]
2. Am I correct that it's evaluating it for each row and/or is there something else going on?
3. Why would it be so different for that environment?  It's the same data model.  There might be differences in data but this seems extreme.  I understand you can't give exact answers without access to the environment, but where should we look?

[1] I realise that one solution is to the change the Java code to use `to_date` directly and not the wrapper function from the dates package.  If needs be I will do this, but I want to understand what is happening first to be confident it will help generally.  And I'd prefer an SQL solution to keep the dates function as a common feature.

Comment: Aside from debugging how many times it is actually called as Paul suggests; have you tried declaring the function as deterministic, or with pragma UDF? Have you looked at the execution plans for both queries to see what changes?

Comment: I tried in our DEV environment.  The `dates` version took 14s.  Adding `deterministic` and `pragma udf` reduced that to 11s.  But the `to_date` version was under 1s so we'll go with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt your issue is repeated calls to your function. Oracle should call that function just twice. If you want to test to be sure, put a `dbms_output.put_line('called me');` line in the function and execute the query, stopping at a reasonable count (`rownum <= 10`) for your test. Did you get 2 "called me" in dbms output, or 20? It should be just 2.

Much more likely is that when you call the function, the optimizer hasn't the slightest clue what sort of date to expect back at parse time. Given that you are looking for a range, two dates a few minutes apart would be very selective, whereas dates a few centuries apart wouldn't be selective at all. Due to this black-box, Oracle is probably taking a guess and estimating the cardinality (# of rows between those two dates) wrongly. This might drive, for example, a full table scan instead of using an index on the date column. Or, possibly, vice-versa. That alone could significantly change your run time one way or the other.

When you use a literal, Oracle knows at parse time exactly what the dates are and therefore how much of a "slice of time" you want. Given it's knowledge of low/high date values, it can estimate how many rows would fall between those dates with much better accuracy, and hopefully choose a more optimal plan.

Due to how the optimizer works, I suggest that you not use that package to do string-date conversion. Use Oracle's `TO_DATE` function instead. I know the programmer in us wants to have a constant defined in one place, but in the world of SQL that's often a luxury we can't afford in order to maintain good performance.

If you absolutely must use the custom functions, then you will likely need to use hints to tell the optimizer how many rows to expect. But those are hard to use when you are querying a view like this, especially since views tend to be used by various top-layer SQLs that have different needs. Another option is if your session only works with date strings of this same format, have your session set its `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`:

`ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'`

Then your query can simply do:

```
select *
from my_view
where regdate >= TO_DATE('2023-12-01T00:00:00')
  and regdate < TO_DATE('2024-01-01T00:00:00')
order by id;
```

Without having to specify the format model. This is one way to define that constant in only one place. But it's generally not a good strategy, as someone is bound to forget that the session has set a custom format model and it could lead to errors elsewhere. All things considered, it's best to just repeat the explicit format model with `TO_DATE` each time it is needed.

Comment: Thanks.  I still don't really understand why it can't get the dates first then sue them to work out the plan, but your explanation makes sense.  The java layer has a helper function to add the dates to the select so we can move the format constant there (SQL will see it as a string, not a constant of course).

Comment: @Adam, because the user-defined function must be called only at runtime, but the plan is decided earlier, at parse-time.